# How to get whole file of external css and js?

Tags: javascript, css, external

Like in subject. I can download whole HTML of a page but I need to download external CSS and JS files too (so I can modify/check them). Do I need to use some scrappers? When page is loaded in a browser it automatically load all css and js - I need something similar. Lets suppose I have access to server - apache or node - do I need to download all css/js files one by one? Any ideas how to get the code of all external css/js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapers like cherio and jsdom are not enought, you can try phantom.js but it's heavy. Easiest way is to just to request (http or request) each css/js file.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you download the HTML of a page (using `Ctrl + S`). Instead of saving it as `Web Page - HTML only` change that option to `Web Page - All files`.

Comment: Hi. This is not the case. I do know how to save the whole page with all of it's components from a browser - and this looks just like you described. The real problem is I need access to external styles and js files of a page. I'm not doing this manually - program connect to a page and need to get content of css and js.